# get values of a element html using a directive. IN ANGULAR.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checkbox, and one directive. I need get the properties of the checkbox. if I put

```
console.log(element)
```

I get this:

[image]

I need get any property of that. but that I put:

```
console.log(element[0])
```

but the result is this.

[image]

How can access to the properties of the my checkbox?

http://jsfiddle.net/3njt42j4/

Comment: you have the reason... write the answer, i will give the correct answer

Comment: Umm, ask for one of the properties rather than the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access. Try running: `console.log(element[0].checked)` and it should log whether the checkbox is checked or not.